# c++ eclipse, unresolved inclusion

Tags: c++, eclipse, iostream

I am super new to programming and have what seems to be a weird issue.  I opened up eclipse to start a new c++ project and all my previous projects do not seem to be ?importing? the...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

They all have errors lines underneath them and Eclipse is saying they are "unresolved inclusion"??

When I go to run the projects it is saying "The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist".

I just checked the folder the project downloads to and nothing seems to be wrong or changed and the same thing happens when I open a new project as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Scott

Comment: This means your compiler toolchain for C++ is not configured properly. This is either because you didn't install it or your Eclipse settings are simply wrong. I suggest you validate your toolchain configuration and verify you're using a proper set of Eclipse packages for C++ development. The stock C++ Eclipse Developers package set [**can be found here**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunar)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have another question regarding this if you don't mind.  I've been using eclipse for c++ for several months now with no problems.  Any idea why it would all of a sudden do this?  Is there maybe an update of some sort that needs to be done you think?

Comment: Was the toolchain removed? I.e. can you open a terminal and run `gcc` or `clang` (whichever you were using) ? It would seem odd that your toolchain would suddenly up-and-disappear.

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  I've never even ran a project using terminal.   I'll google how to do that and get back to you.   I did find however that Xcode needed to be reinstalled.  So I installed Xcode and the command line tools which I think has the g++ compiler included.  I also erased eclipse and reinstalled it and the same errors are showing but it seems to be running the projects no problem.  Maybe it's just something funky going on with eclipse.

Comment: So, I just think it is something weird going on with Eclipse.  The programs are running fine now, and I ran a couple in a text editor using terminal and they're running ok there too.  Thanks for your help!  Any recommendations on a different C++ IDE for a mac?